# Spring JdbcTemplate batchUpdate issue always returning -3

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate, batch-updates

I am trying to use the batchUpdate on Springs jdbcTemplate but all i'm getting back is an int array of -3's.  Below is the code I'm running. The array list "batch" contains inserts and updates.

```
String[] stmts = batch.toArray(new String[batch.size()]);
int[] result = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(stmts);
```

The result array contains
    [-3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, -3, ... ]

Using
 - Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE
 - jtds driver 1.3.0
 - SQL Server 2005

Has anyone come across this?

Answer (score 1):

It was found that batchUpdate does not like comments in the sql it is given. Once the comments were removed the update worked fine.